# How can I make set/get work in redis inside docker?

Tags: python, docker, redis

I have checked that REDIS is running in docker, but the set/get methods in the python script are not working. They are working fine outside docker but. Can anyone please help what could be done

I am using redis locally

```
"redis_host":"127.0.0.1",
"redis_port":6379,

REDIS_HOST = config['redis_host']
REDIS_PORT = config['redis_port']
rdb = redis.StrictRedis(host=REDIS_HOST, port=REDIS_PORT, db=0)

key = 'user_id' + '.' + str(user_id)
print("getting key from redis",rdb.get(key))
```

Comment: Can you explain little bit more ? Where is your python redis client , how you are connected to redis docker container ?

Comment: I am using redis locally

"redis_host":"127.0.0.1",
"redis_port":6379,

REDIS_HOST = config['redis_host']
REDIS_PORT = config['redis_port']
rdb = redis.StrictRedis(host=REDIS_HOST, port=REDIS_PORT, db=0)

key = 'user_id' + '.' + str(user_id)
print("getting key from redis",rdb.get(key))

Comment: docker run -it -d --name redis-server -v redis-volume:/data -p 6379:6379 -d redis

Comment: What doesn't work?  Is this script running in a container too, or on the host?

Answer (score 1):

First, the code you posted doesn't contain a SET command. Does this key exist in your Redis instance?

Other than that I can't tell what redis client you are using but I'm using redis-py python client and it works this way in a docker container of Ubuntu Redis & Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from redis import Redis, RedisError

app = Flask(__name__)
redis = Redis(host='redis', port=6379)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    redis.incr('hits')
    return 'Hello World! I have been seen %s times.' % redis.get('hits')
```

Comment: yep, the script checks if key exits do this(get the key), if key doesnot exist set the key, i forgot to put the code for that, but now redis is working fine, altering a docker line in rebuild, thanks